# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot install VS Code Remote

Tags: 16.04

I have installed the latest VS Code (1.34.0) on my Ubuntu 16.04. Then I tried to install VS Code Remote, but failed. The error message is

`Unable to install because, the extension 'ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack' compatible with current version '1.34.0' of VS Code is not found.`

Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Visual Studio Code Insiders to use this extension. To install  Visual Studio Code Insiders (*code-insiders*) open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install code-insiders --classic
```

[image: code-insiders]

[image: Remote - SSH extension]
<sup>**Remote - SSH extension is published by Microsoft**</sup>